# How to show image/word document/pdf in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a BLOB field in my table and the user can save anything like image.pdf.work document to this field.
In my crystal report when i try to show this field if it has an image it will be shown but if it has a PDF of WORD I see empty area.

I am looking for a solution which will enable me show anything saved in this BLOB column in crystal report.Is it possible?

Somebody at below link said no , but I am realy hoping some expert here can suggesst a solution

[SAP forum](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3482140)

Comment: I can give you and idea, I don't know if it will work but you can try something like putting that field inside a sub-report and call it using an stored procedure. I mean try to open it with a sql call

Comment: Thanks cojimarmiami , can you please eloborate your suggesstion in more detail. As I said I am already reading the file from database using sql call.I have a select query which reads the blob field and I am using that field in my report.

Comment: that is something I've never done before, but are you able to open that document using a query on SQL? I mean not in crystal reports, directly in SQL using a query that call that field and open it. If you are able to do that, you can create and stored procedure using that query, put it in a subreport and link it to your main report. Is that make sense? This is just a thought, I am not sure if it will work.